# How to make Firebase hosting /api rewrite request to app engine service

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Currently I have the below firebase.json. I wanna rewrite all requests of https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/api point to https://myapp.appspot.com/api (one of my app engine services). Somethink like the `dispatch.yaml` that appengine uses, how can I do that? I don't wanna use a DNS and a subdomain like api.xxxx.com/api

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api**",
        "destination": "https://myapp.appspot.com/api"
      },
      {
        "source": "!/api/**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Hosting doesn't support rewriting paths to Google App Engine. Your [rewrite options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) currently are:

- [Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#direct_requests_to_a_function)
- [Cloud Run container](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#direct_requests_to_a_cloud_run_container)
- [Dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#dynamic_links)

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a google function in golang to proxy /api requests to the api engine service. Do you have one tip to make it with a better approach @abraham?

Comment: Personally I would use a subdomain or explore ways of running the GAE code in a container or Function.

Comment: @BrunoTomé could you post your details to your golang function proxy?

Comment: @ahong https://gist.github.com/ibrunotome/7a0ccc572cc48693aab80523b8a8874b but this is not in production anymore, so I can't help more than that.